# jQuery working on Safari but not in iOS - what can I do to debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, safari

I'm using xCode simulator to test out jQuery on a site I'm developing but I can't figure out why it's not working.. On Safari webkit it's working fine.

[The site is here](http://connor.la/sandbox/dmani/mob.html) while it would be helpful to find out what's wrong, I'm wondering what I can do in the future when using Simulator to 'inspect' or see javascript console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug Safari on an iOS device or simulator using the developer tools in the desktop version of Safari see https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787 and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html